# How to use Laravel Sanctum without web session?

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, laravel-sanctum

I want use my app only via api requests (token authorization)
Problem:
I have swagger to test queries. If I send one request with valid token, I can send any another requests without token and I didn't become an error "Unauthenticated"

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

config/sanctum.php

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    'guard' => ['web'],

    'expiration' => null,

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
...
}
```

I want turn of checking of session and leave only token validation

Comment: inside your config/auth.php , under `guards`, where is your api configuration ?

Comment: You can try commenting out `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` in your api middleware

Comment: @Win nowhere( I tried add api and remove web but become an error "Auth guard [web] is not defined."

Comment: @apokryfos tried, become 401 =>  "message": "Unauthenticated."

Comment: @exstreme do not remove guards web, but please add second guard. ...  `'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => true,
        ],` ... and move all your routes from web.php to api.php .. than test again, this time change url by adding api  `https://your.domain.name/api/your-path`

Comment: add middleware to your secured routes as suggested here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#protecting-mobile-api-routes

Comment: I thought you wanted the 401? Basically you set up [SPA authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) and you need to set up [API token authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication).

Comment: @apokryfos api token already setted up and work fine. No, I can't authorize any request with valid token with commenting EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful. I want 401 for requests without token

Comment: @Win added, wasn't helpful(

Comment: `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` will start the session which is what you do not want so try going through the api token auth setup again step by step

Comment: @exstreme , try what apokryfos said, remove / comment middleware `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` , unless you want to use it as SPA, and after that inside your `config/sanctum.php` there is `guard => [web]`, it is used inside `Laravel\Sanctum\Guard::__invoke` , the default is using [web] which will also trigger middleware `StartSession` , either change to [api] or comment out `StartSession`

Comment: Win @apokryfos thanks a lot, a problem solved. The problem was in swagger, it didn't add Bearer in Authorization